# Retrieve youtube playlist wrong when playlist items count over 100

Tags: json, api, youtube, youtube-api

I got playlist items wrong no matter v2 or v3 api I used.

test playlists are here: [test1113](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LD-67jlsY9I&list=PLLp2yjw6iubr0dAuhxmY15n3tqGYbI8BV), and [another test playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMX7OpDDWSE&list=PLLp2yjw6iubpvG98UIzj8tlpZ_W_z04ED)

the example is using test1113

When I call "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLLp2yjw6iubr0dAuhxmY15n3tqGYbI8BV?v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=25", it returns 25 items, from position 1 to position 26, with position 5 missing.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLLp2yjw6iubr0dAuhxmY15n3tqGYbI8BV?v=2&alt=json&start-index=26&max-results=25 returns position 31 to position 56. This makes 4 videos missing.

Call from 51st video to 75th video even worse.
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLLp2yjw6iubr0dAuhxmY15n3tqGYbI8BV?v=2&alt=json&start-index=51&max-results=25

The first video returned is not even in the playlist. The last returned is position 88. (but according to the json file returned, the yt$position is 108.)

You can call the url until you get all the videos in the playlist. But there is only 80 of them, according to the api, the total result should be 137. A lot of videos in the playlist are missing by calling from api.

Both v2 and v3 api returns the same result.

What did I do wrong? Or Is there a problem with YouTube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe related to this bug report:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6062
See also:
[youtube api playlistitems deleted videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189885/youtube-api-playlistitems-deleted-videos/22113882?noredirect=1#comment33554877_22113882)

Comment: Thank you. It looks like an YouTube api problem

Comment: I tested it. When no deleted videos in that playlist, the bug is still there. It seems that the api that retrive the playlist items has the problem no matter weather there are deleted videos in it

Comment: Yeah, when i retrieve your playlist PLLp2yjw6iubpvG98UIzj8tlpZ_W_z04ED using api version 3 and compare the results with the playlist shown on YouTube, i also don't get all videos returned.